# Integrate jenkins with selenium web driver

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

How can I integrate jenkins with selenium web driver? Also when I am going to download jenkins plugin for selenium here : https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/  I am getting diff. folder related to selenium so which one I should download - seleniumhq??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it all depends on what you want to do with Selenium.

SeleniumHQ is the 1.0 version so you should go with the webdriver/Selenium 2. The [main plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) embeds a [selenium grid server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) into jenkins

Alternatively, you can use a web service to run all your tests, which gives you many more test browsers and many provide their own Jenkins plugins like [Sauce Labs](https://docs.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/jenkins/) (free for a certain amount of runs)

As to the test scripts, there are bindings for many languages so you can use your favourite language or the one which your main development is written in http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp - this not a full list

Answer (score 0):

With the Jenkins Selenium Grid server mentioned above you can connect multiple nodes (local or remote machines) and you can test multiple concurrent browsers and sessions via threading or other mechanisms. I have found that sufficient without having to use Sauce Labs specially that you can use jenkins variables such as jenkins.label, jenkins.nodeName to connect and test various platforms. There is good documentation on using the jenkins variables here 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin